# how to show box over image with css :after

Tags: html, css, overlay, pseudo-element

I have web application with some more pages and i cant change the all pages, but i can change the css code.

I have a img with "thumbnail" tag with css class to show the image.

i want to show a box over image with css.

```css
.thumbnail {position:relative;width:128px;height:128px;}
.thumbnail:after {position:absolute;width:20px;height:128px;top:0px;right:0px;background-color:#ff0;content:" ";z-index:100;}
```

```html
<img class="thumbnail" src="http://mrizvandi.com/Media/Image/QRCode/ContactInfo.jpg" />
```

When i use the :after in css, i cant see any effect!

Is there any solution to show overlay box without additional tag and just use css?

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. Replaced elements could not have `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements.

> Replaced content
>
> If the computed value of the part of the 'content' property that ends
>   up being used is a single URI, then the element or pseudo-element is a
>   replaced element. The box model defines different rules for the layout
>   of replaced elements than normal elements. Replaced elements do not
>   have '::before' and '::after' pseudo-elements; the 'content' property
>   in the case of replaced content replaces the entire contents of the
>   element's box.
>
> To insert text around replaced content, '::outside::before' and
>   '::outside::after' may be used.

You could solve the problem by selecting a parent element to place the pseudo-element.

Reference: [w3.org - Generated and Replaced Content Module - Replaced content](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/#replacedContent)

Comment: Thank you, i change my strategy to solove the problem and client request. Use a <div> parent amd contain <img> tag.

Comment: Nice to hear that, you are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Because of browser behavior and css rules, i change my strategy, and change all pages ;)

Add a div as container for image.
with style "position:relative"

Add image as child of div.

Add :after class to container.

```css
.thumbnail {position:relative;width:128px;height:128px;}
.thumbnail:after {position:absolute;width:20px;height:128px;top:0px;right:0px;background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);content:" ";z-index:100;}
.thumbnail>img {width:128px;height:128px;}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img src="http://mrizvandi.com/Media/Image/QRCode/ContactInfo.jpg" />
</div>
```

Thanks to all friends